# Openstack KILO installation

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install openstack KILO; when i try to create service entity and endpoint API, it say cannot authenticate without OS_auth? I am following this installation guide http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/...
Please help to solve this??